# How to return a specific range of indexes from within in a JSON Array?

Tags: arrays, json, array.prototype.map

I have this array of objects that I retrieved from an API. It is continuously being updated everyday. The array consists of a timeseries of cases for everyday. I want to use this array to return the cases for each date for the last week. I have fetched the country name and filtered the array, so it only shows the user's country's array.  I was thinking I can map across the dates of the array to find the last 7 indexes. Is there a way to do this?

```
useEffect(() => {
      axios
        .get("https://api.covid19india.org/v4/min/timeseries.min.json")
        .then((response) => {
          setEarliest2(response.data);

          const stateArray = response.data.filter(
            (item) => item.country === mappedLocation.stateShort
          );
}
```

```
{
  "AN": {
    "dates": {
      "2020-03-26": {
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 1
        },
        "delta7": {
          "confirmed": 1
        },
        "total": {
          "confirmed": 1
        }
      },
      "2020-03-27": {
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 5
        },
        "delta7": {
          "confirmed": 6
        },
        "total": {
          "confirmed": 6
        }
      },
      "2020-03-28": {
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 3
        },
        "delta7": {
          "confirmed": 9
        },
        "total": {
          "confirmed": 9
        }
      },
      "2020-03-29": {
        "delta7": {
          "confirmed": 9
        },
        "total": {
          "confirmed": 9
        }
      },
      "2020-03-30": {
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 1
        },
        "delta7": {
          "confirmed": 10
        },
        "total": {
          "confirmed": 10
        }
      },
  ...
}
```

```
const DataSet = (props) => {
return [
    {
      x: new Date(
        parseInt(moment().format("YYYY")),
        parseInt(moment().format("M")),
        parseInt(moment().format("DD")) - 7
      ),
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON array. `response.data` is an array of objects.

Comment: And why is this tagged with `typescript` and `react-native`?

Comment: Grab the "dates" (`Object.keys()`), sort them, get the first/last (depending on the sort order) seven

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I meant to say an array of objects, but it is a JSON. It's tagged with them because I am building with `react-native` and `typescript`? Otherwise, why would I tag those? Could you provide an example of your answer?

Comment: Axios automatically parses the JSON to arrays and objects. If it was truly still JSON, it would be a string, and you'd get an error when you wrote `response.data.filter` since strings don't have a `filter` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use ES2019+:

```js
const getPastCasesByCountry = (response, country, pastDays) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(response[country].dates)
    .sort(([date1], [date2]) => date1.localeCompare(date2))
    .slice(-pastDays)
);

const last7DaysAN = getPastCasesByCountry(response, 'AN', 7);
```

This uses

- the handy [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) + [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) combo which gives you the ability to work with an object essentialy the same way as with an array
- the fact that [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) can take a negative start index, which is an offset from the end – as we needed here

#### Convert to data set

To convert to `DataSet` as described in your question, I'd change the function a bit:

```js
const getPastCasesByCountry = (response, country, pastDays) => 
  Object.entries(response[country].dates)
    .sort(([date1], [date2]) => date1.localeCompare(date2))
    .slice(-pastDays)

const DataSet = (casesByDate) => casesByDate.map(([dateString, cases]) => ({
  x: new Date(dateString),
  y: cases.total.confirmed
}))

const data = DataSet(getPastCasesByCountry(response, 'AN', 7));
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a way to return this array object, so I can use it in other files maybe using props and hooks?

Comment: An object is an unsorted collection of key-value pairs. Therefor this answer only works when the order of the properties ends in the correct order after parsing the response - which is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Andreas You're right, thanks for the catch! I just wanted to show an alternative to `reduce` (as in @denis-t's answer), but forgot about order ‍♂️ I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: @Andreas @ rsmeral thank you both for your insight on this. Do you have an answer to my question above?

Comment: What do you mean by "other files"? Like child components? And what do you mean by "this array object"? The object containing the past 7 days for a particular country?

Comment: My goal is to use this object containing the past 7 days for a particular country and pass it into a dataset array with x being the date, and y being the confirmed case value. I'll edit the code to clarify more.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of dates, then sort it, slice it and get cases from the original response:

```
function getLast7DaysCases (response) {
  const cases = response.data['AN'].dates
  return Object.keys(cases)
    .sort()
    .reverse()
    .slice(0, 7)
    .reduce((acc, k) => ({ ...acc, [k]: cases[k] }), {})
}
```

Comment: Instead of `.sort().reverse()` just `.slice()` from the end of the list with `.slice(-7)`